# Get 404 when using url parameters to filter custom post type archive page created with wp bakery post grid

Tags: 404-error, pre-get-posts

I created a custom post type named tutors_quiz than I create custom taxonomy named tutor-quiz-tag.

I create an archive page with wp bakery post grid. screenshot https://prnt.sc/VdvDp9-ekt3c

Now I want if url is `https://tutaid.com/tutors_quiz/?quiz_tag=java` it need to show filtered result but it show 404.

Below is code I used with pre_get_posts.

```
function custom_tutors_quiz_filter($query) {
    if (is_admin() || !$query->is_main_query()) {
        return;
    }

    if (isset($_GET['quiz_tag'])) {
        $query->set('post_type', 'tutors_quiz');
        $query->set('tax_query', array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'tutor-quiz-tag', 
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $_GET['quiz_tag'],
            ),
        ));
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'custom_tutors_quiz_filter');
```

any suggestions please.